# @Column(unique=true) and uniqueConstraints both not working

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate to generate a MySQL table but I'm having issues trying to get it to use unique constraints. I've tried these two options:

This annotation at the class level

```
@Table(name = "users",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"nickname", "email"}))
```

And this on the variable:

```
@Column(nullable=false,name="nickname",unique=true)
    private String nickname;
```

But neither seem to work. When I look at the DDL of the table created using either of these it is missing any constraints, and my code is able to insert the same record as many times as it wants with no errors or issues. I've tried looking through other answers on here but all of those seem to end with one of these two methods working, so I assume I'm doing something wrong and just missing it.

Let me know if you need any more info, and thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Why do you have also "email" at class level?

Comment: That was just from playing around with it, as email is another field I want to have as unique. But it makes no difference if I have both of them there or just one. still gives the same result

Comment: Does your hibernate update existing table with data, with no data at all or does it hibernate table from scratch?

Comment: Hibernate is creating the table from scratch. I'm dropping the table manually each time since I have it set up to only create the table if it doesn't exist

Comment: I'm using MySQL Workbench so I'm just inspecting the table there and looking at the DDL. The constraints definitely aren't there as I'm able to insert elements which would violate it, i.e. I've inserted the exact same record multiple times